# Como criar um array com os meses

Tags: php, array, data

Boa tarde, estou prestando manutenção em um código que apresenta um gráfico, o eixo de X apresenta os últimos 11 meses e o mês atual, quem o escreveu inseriu os meses manualmente e queria automatizar, pensei em fazê-lo da seguinte forma:

```
$meses = array(date(m)-11, date(m)-10, date(m)-9, date(m)-8, date(m)-7, date(m)-6, date(m)-5, date(m)-4, date(m)-3, date(m)-2, date(m)-1, date(m));
```

o problema é que fazendo assim os meses serão mostrados na forma de número e eu preciso que apareça no formato date(M), mas a função não aceita subtração 'date(M)-1';

Comment: Esse gráfico está sendo gerado como ?

Comment: highcharts.js e jquery.js com os valores / meses adicionados manualmente.

Comment: Posta o código do chart

Comment: ele está todo compactado em uma única linha e ilegível :(

Comment: Mas em algum arquivo tem o código que monta o gráfico.

Comment: aqui:
$('#container').highcharts({
chart: {
zoomType: 'xy'
},
title: {
text: 'Gráfico Objetivo <?php echo date('d/m/Y'); ?>'
},
xAxis: [{
categories: ['Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
crosshair: true
}],
yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
}, { // Secondary yAxis
opposite: true
}],
legend: {
layout: 'vertical',
align: 'left',
x: 100,
verticalAlign: 'top',
y: 100,
floating: true,
backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'
},

Comment: continuação


series: [{
name: 'Concluídos,
type: 'column',
data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0],

}, {
name: 'Objetivo',
type: 'spline',
data: [1, 4, 4, 5, 8, 8, 11, 15, 15],
}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta que após calculado o mês, converte-lo em texto:

```
function convert_date($before){
     return DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', (date('m')-$before))->format('F');
}
```

Depois é só utilizar dessa forma:

```
$meses = array(
     convert_date(11),
     convert_date(10),
     convert_date(9),
     convert_date(8),
     convert_date(7),
     convert_date(6),
     convert_date(5),
     convert_date(4),
     convert_date(3),
     convert_date(2),
     convert_date(1)
 );
```

Comment: essa função convert_date está dando erro no meu código, qnd eu chamo ela dá erro de execução :(

Comment: o PHP instalado em minha máquina que é uma versão antiga e incompatível, 5.2, rodei em um php sandbox online e funcionou da forma que eu preciso, obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

```
$meses = array(1 => "Janeiro", 2 => "Fevereiro", 3 => "Março", 4 => "Abril", 5 => "Maio", 6 => "Junho", 7 => "Julho", 8 => "Agosto", 9 => "Setembro", 10 => "Outubro", 11 => "Novembro", 12 => "Dezembro");
```

depois:

```
 echo $meses[date("n")];
```